# How to find the other point of a Unix domain socket on Mac OS X to write/read it?

Tags: macos, sockets, network-programming, netstat, lsof

I listed open file for a process (a daemon) on my box which runs Mac OS X 10.5 :

```
>lsof  -p 89
COMMAND PID     USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE  SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
...
xxxxx   89 xxxxxxxx    9u  unix 0x34f8990       0t0          ->0x34f8880
```

I 'd like to find a way to open this socket and write in it. (that's my obsession this time ..)

How to find the i-node/name of the underlying file in order to reach that socket?
Is there a way to address programatically this adress 0x34f888 from a **shell script**?
If not so, how to do programatically ?

As a comment, I've launched the netstat command and get this result:

```
> netstat -u
Active LOCAL (UNIX) domain sockets
Address  Type   Recv-Q Send-Q    Inode     Conn     Refs  Nextref Addr
...
 34f8990 stream      0      0        0  34f8880        0        0
...
 34f8880 stream      0      0        0  34f8990        0        0
...
```

I am not a network/socket guru. Hope this could give more information

Comment: any luck finding an answer to this?